# how to create a b-tree index in H2 database?

Tags: database, indexing, h2

i want to create a **b-tree index** in **H2 database**. Give me the query with example to create a b-tree index on a table attribute in H2DB.

The index must be a **b-tree** index not the clustered or any other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a persistent database, the default index is of type b-tree. So use [`CREATE INDEX`](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_index) as you would normally:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_NAME ON TEST(NAME);
```

By the way, within H2, even clustered indexes are b-tree indexes internally.

This is true for persistent databases only. In-memory databases (`jdbc:h2:mem:...`) don't use b-tree indexes - they use hash indexes (hash map) and AVL-tree indexes.